# SQL Syntax causes confusion (very basic!)

Tags: sql, oracle

Right so I've learned the correct way of selecting max values like so:

```
select * 
from table 
where salary = (select avg(salary) from table);
```

I now want to select values higher than average, and thought hey "Easy, just add '>') I've tried each of the places below, and around parentheses; to no avail. This is giving me a headache, unreasonably tricky for such a seemingly easy task.

```
select * 
from table 
where salary = (select >avg>(>salary>) from table);
```

What to do? Also, sorry to bother you with such a tedious question, but I can't find where to use the operator in the Oracle book.

Comment: Seriously ? is this a joke?

Comment: Take a deep breath . Relax . And code .

Comment: Trashing your own question is not reasonable. Yes, it was downvoted, most likely because of the original title. IMO it's not a bad question, and it got a correct answer which you properly accepted. I suggest that the next time you ask a question (and I truly hope you will) you stick with facts, and avoid language which will get people riled up. (Yes, a title such as "SQL makes me wanna puke" will do that around here :-). Best of luck.

Comment: Right, my bad. Will obviously take that into account. My apologies.

Comment: @pubba - I understand the feeling because I get a bit peeved when something I've put up gets downvoted, but on the other hand reputation on StackOverflow is just a combined scorekeeping and motivational system. A positive rep change doesn't make us better people - a negative rep change doesn't make us worse people. StackOverflow has become popular because the people who started it figured out a way to make it a game - and (stupid monkeys that we are :-) we all love games. (Now, if they could figure out how to hand out bananas... :-)

Comment: @Raptor - I rolled the question back to its best state, and I think OP has had time to chill a bit. Move along, folks - nothin' to see here. Move along now...

Comment: @pubba - if it helps, I've seen worse. I went to college with a guy who was expelled for taking a sledgehammer to a terminal (back in the days where "terminals" were Selectric typewriters with lots of very expensive electronics attached) when the computer was taken down after he'd spent all night editing a program without ever saving his work. Not good... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
select * from table where salary > (select avg(salary)from table);
```